# Event is raised continuously, slows down code. How to handle it with threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

I know there is a better way to do this. I'm fairly new to multithreaded programming, however raising my event on a new thread like the code below allows my application to get a higher FPS with the Kinect.

When the object of my KinectService class is initalized, inside that method I do this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() =>
{
    sensor.AllFramesReady += new EventHandler<AllFramesReadyEventArgs>(sensor_AllFramesReady);
    KinectSensor.KinectSensors.StatusChanged += new    EventHandler<StatusChangedEventArgs>(Kinects_StatusChanged);
});
t.Start();
```

Which in turn calls this method:

```
void sensor_AllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e) 
{
    using (DepthImageFrame depthFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
    {
        if (depthFrame == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        byte[] pixels = GenerateColoredBytes(depthFrame);            
        int stride = depthFrame.Width * 4;
        BitmapSource test = BitmapSource.Create(depthFrame.Width, depthFrame.Height,
                    96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, pixels, stride);

        test.Freeze();

        if (FrameChanged != null)
        {
            FrameChanged(test);
        }
    }    
}
```

FrameChanged(test) passes the newly created bitmap back to the viewmodel which then updates the source of an image. Is this a terrible way to do this? Giving an event it's own thread feels wrong, however it makes my application run a lot faster. Any pointers?

Comment: This doesn't do what you describe. Your thread adds delegates as listeners to the events, then completes. The event will be dispatched in the context of the thread that dispatches it, as normal. Are you sure this is the source of your speedup?

Comment: It is yeah. If I don't have this then the image choppily updates and many frames are lost.

Comment: It doesn't seem terrible to put it on its own thread (if that is how it's speeding up), but if there's a loop somewhere down the line that I'm not seeing, you could try using `Application.DoEvents()` instead. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx)

Comment: @benjgorman spender is right though... this shouldn't change anything about how the events fire and IMO is more likely a side effect of whatever changes you made to enable adding the delegates in their own thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events are fired on the same thread that called them, and there isn't anything in the documentation for `KinectSensor.AllFramesReady` to say otherwise.

So in your code sensor.AllFramesReady won't fire another event until your event handler (`sensor_AllFramesReady`) returns.

A better way to do it *possibly* is to change your event handler to spawn off a thread and immediately return.  I.e.

```
void sensor_AllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)  
{
    var frameReadyThread = new Thread(() =>
    using (DepthImageFrame depthFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame()) 
    {
        //
    }
    frameReadyThread.Start();
}
```

You will need to do some synchronisation though within frameReadyThread to ensure that the following is true,

1. Frames are not handled out of order, you don't want *Frame 1* to **update after** *Frame 2*
2. Frames are abandoned when they are no longer doing useful work rather than steal CPU.
3. If you're implementing your own thread dispatcher, that you scale appropriately to the machine you are on.  For example, if you have access to 8 cores, and your handler code is CPU bound, its unlikely that you'll see any benefit if you have more than 8 threads.